# How to initialise a GPU array using memory address in pycuda?

Tags: python, c++, pointers, memory-address, pycuda

I have a c++ code that gives image array output in GPU memory. I want to do further processing and image analytics using pycuda. I am trying to make GPU array as:

For testing purpose, I have created an array in c++ as:

```
        const int arraySize = 5;
        const int a[arraySize] = {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 };
        int* dev_a = nullptr;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, arraySize * sizeof(int));
        cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, arraySize * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        printf("dev_a : %p\n", dev_a);
```

Suppose, here I get GPU memory address as '0x7f3454800000'. I am using this address to create GPUarray as:

```
from pycuda.gpuarray import GPUArray
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
from pycuda.driver import PointerHolderBase
drv.init()


class Holder(PointerHolderBase):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.gpudata = '0x7f5954800000'

    def get_pointer(self):
        return self.gpudata

    def __int__(self):
        return self.__index__()

    # without an __index__ method, arithmetic calls to the GPUArray backed by this pointer fail
    # not sure why, this needs to return some integer, apparently
    def __index__(self):
        return self.gpudata


array = GPUArray((1,5), dtype=np.int32, gpudata=Holder())

print(array.get())
```

When I am running the code, I am getting error as:

```
File "array_test.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(array.get())
  File "/home/govindam/anaconda3/envs/tf_c2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycuda/gpuarray.py", line 305, in get
    _memcpy_discontig(ary, self, async_=async_, stream=stream)
  File "/home/govindam/anaconda3/envs/tf_c2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycuda/gpuarray.py", line 1309, in _memcpy_discontig
    drv.memcpy_dtoh(dst, src.gpudata)
TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type unsigned long long from this Python object of type st
```

How to give the memory address while creating GPUarray so that I am avoid copying from GPU to CPU and again to GPU?

Comment: How do you know that the address is always `self.gpudata = '0x7f5954800000'`? How do you call your C++ code before invoking the python code?

Comment: That's true that the address may not be always '0x7f5954800000'. Here, I have not freed the memory from the GPU. So, for this program, this should work.  Later, I can pass this address dynamically from c++ to python. I am using ctypes to call c++ from python. Right now, I am compiling c++ using g++ and nvcc.

Comment: OK, but in this case, do you have 2 separate binaries running? C++ program just to give you the address, and then you run python after you obtain the address? I am not entirely sure about the GPU addr space, but for sure you cannot do this with standard CPU memory addresses.

Comment: Yes, I have 2 binaries running. I am streaming data using c++ from the camera and later, want to use for analyzing the frames in the gpu with the help of analytics. Transferring the frame from c++ to python using ctypes and again copying it gpu for further processing is creating overhead. I want to avoid this and directly want to create GPUarray from the address pointed out by c++. How do you suggest this should be done? Any help would be great.

Comment: Hmmm, good question. I don't know, but I will take a look.